# Unable to load a Password Encrypted Pem

Tags: c#, ssh, rsa

I am able to load an unencrypted PEM file with `RSA.ImportFromPem()` with no issues, but I am not able to load a PEM file when it's password encrypted.

Here is the code I am attempting to use.

```
var pwRSA = RSA.Create();
pwRSA.ImportFromEncryptedPem(pwPemKey, "password1");
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=No supported key formats were found. Check that the input represents the contents of a PEM-encoded key file, not the path to such a file. (Parameter 'input')
  Source=System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms
  StackTrace:
   at Internal.Cryptography.PemKeyImportHelpers.ImportEncryptedPem[TPass](ReadOnlySpan`1 input, ReadOnlySpan`1 password, ImportEncryptedKeyAction`1 importAction)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.ImportFromEncryptedPem(ReadOnlySpan`1 input, ReadOnlySpan`1 password)
   at RSAEncryptionTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\source\tests\RSAEncryptionTest\Program.cs:line 57
```

Given this is just a test, I don't mind sharing the private key.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,F7922A7F105CC716E9A19297BAC0BE49
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK `ImportFromEncryptedPem()` supports only PKCS#8 format, your encrypted key has PKCS#1 format. `ImportFromPem()` supports both. A conversion from PKCS#1 to PKCS#8 and vice versa (with or without encryption) is possible e.g. with OpenSSL.

Comment: Thank you, I have a lot to learn about these different formats.  When I create the key PKCS 8, it imports fine.  But that leaves me trying to import an Encrypted PKCS1.  I have been unable to get `ImportFromPem()` to work on an encrypted key.  I poorly assumed `ImportFromEncryptedPem()` was the same format except encrypted. I am testing to see if I can move the requirements to PKCS8. Otherwise, I am stuck trying to work with PKCS1 due to other systems.

Comment: `ImportFromPem()` supports only *unencrypted* keys (maybe I wasn't clear enough). If you don't want to convert your encrypted PKCS#1 key with an external tool like OpenSSL, an alternative is BouncyCastle/C#, which supports the import of encrypted (and of course also unencrypted) private keys in PKCS#8 **and** PKCS#1 format.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance!!  I was able to get this to work by loading the PKCS8 key and using that for encrypting/decrypting data and then exporting a PKCS1 key and using that in Renci.sshnet for connecting in a different part of the app.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Topaco above, the key is to convert the private key into PKCS#8 format. Since no one else included it here, here's the OpenSSL command I used to accomplish this:

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform PEM -topk8 -in private_key.pem -out private_key2.pem
```

After doing this I was able to import private_key2.pem using ImportFromEncryptedPem

Comment: Just curious , do we also have to convert our certificate to pkcs8 format. I have my certificate and key in pkcs12 format. I am able to convert my key using this command to pkcs8 format. But, unsure about certificate. Thanks